# How to add compile dependency to javadoc class path in gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle

In gradle if I my project depends on another package, for example:

```gradle
compile 'com.example:foo:0.82.2'
```

And in my javadoc, it references symbol in that package.

Then if I run javadoc task, it will say error: reference not found

I know I should add that package to class path, just like the following way to add android library

```gradle
classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
```

But how could I know the classpath for my dependency except add a hard coding path point to the gradle cache?

Comment: Here's the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34572606/1118475