# how to generate javadoc of android library based on Aspectj?

Tags: android, aspectj, javadoc

I used `Aspectj` in android library. I want to generate javadoc of it.
So i write task like this:
build.gradle

```
task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}
task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}
```

when i run this task, i get error:

```
/Users/**/MyAspect.java:6: error: package org.aspectj.lang not exist
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
                        ^
/Users/**/MyAspect.java:7: error: package org.aspectj.lang.annotation not exist
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;

...

javadoc: warning - can not find class Aspect。
javadoc: warning - can not find class Pointcut。
javadoc: warning - can not find class Aspect。
```

anyone knows how to generate `Javadoc` of library based on `Aspectj`? If you can help me, i will be appreciate for it. Thank you very much, guys.

Comment: How about putting `aspectjrt-xx.yy.zz.jar` on the classpath?

Comment: @kriegaex, thank you, i will try it. Later put result here

Comment: @kriegaex, i have comile with ```implementation 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.13'```. So, this can not fix this problem.

Comment: I don't generate JavaDoc very often and never use Gradle, always Maven. But maybe you can print the classpath on the console  in the javadoc task and see if the AspectJ runtime is really there for the Javadoc generator. Somehow it is not found, obviously. As you did not provide a full [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I can only speculate. So you could help others help you by editing your question and providing an MCVE.

Comment: @kriegaex, thank you very much.I am appreciate for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all guys. I have fixed my problem.
I add task like this to set `Javadoc` task's classpath:

```
afterEvaluate {
    javadoc.classpath += files(android.libraryVariants.collect { variant -> variant.javaCompile.classpath.files
    })
}
```

I got answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571371/android-studio-javadoc-cannot-find-symbol/34572606#34572606)