# Javadoc and Android studio : Cannot find symbol

Tags: android, javadoc

I am currently working an Android app (on Android Studio, using mainly Java).

I want to generate javadoc (using the Tools -> Generate menu).

Following this other post ([Android Studio Javadoc: Cannot find symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571371/android-studio-javadoc-cannot-find-symbol)), I added the following code to my build.gradle :

```
task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work. When I try to generate the javadoc, I have the following errors (and a lot more) :

```
error: cannot find symbol
import android.Manifest;
...
error: package android.compat.annotation does not exist
import android.compat.annotation.UnsupportedAppUsage;
...
error: package android.compat.annotation does not exist
import android.compat.annotation.UnsupportedAppUsage;
...
```

I tried adding the following to the gradle file :

```
afterEvaluate {
    javadoc.classpath += files(android.libraryVariants.collect { variant ->
        variant.javaCompileProvider.get().classpath.files
    })
}
```

But with this added, I get an error when pressing sync gradle :

```
> Could not get unknown property 'libraryVariants' for extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.
```

Comment: Could you solve it? I am suffering from the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I came along the same way and after a while I figured out that it's because I'm not developing a library, but an application. Consequently, you just exchange `libraryVariants` for `applicationVariants`.

```
afterEvaluate {
    javadocs.classpath += files(android.applicationVariants.collect { variant ->
        variant.javaCompileProvider.get().classpath.files
    })
}
```